# NSolve and MemoryAllocationFailure

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I have a code like,

`ReplaceAll[Table [  Subscript[u,n] == (0.2   Subscript[u, n + 1] + 0.8  Subscript[u, n - 1]) +Subscript[u, n]^3, {n, 1, 20} ], {Subscript[u, 0] -> 0, Subscript[u, 21] -> 0} ]`

```
NSolve[%26, {Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2], Subscript[u, 3], Subscript[u, 4], Subscript[u, 5], Subscript[u, 6], Subscript[u, 7], Subscript[u, 8], Subscript[u, 9], Subscript[u, 10], Subscript[u,11], Subscript[u, 12], Subscript[u, 13], Subscript[u, 14], Subscript[u, 15], Subscript[u, 16], Subscript[u, 17], Subscript[u, 18], Subscript[u, 19], Subscript[u, 20]}]
```

and when I run it, 
`SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure".`warnings I got. Is there any way to calculate these nonlinear equations?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2):

No chance to solve it with NSolve. I think you would need a future quantum computer.

Define a version for general number of parameters.

```
rp[nmax_] := 
  ReplaceAll[
   Table[Subscript[u, 
 n] == (2/10 Subscript[u, n + 1] + 8/10 Subscript[u, n - 1]) + 
 Subscript[u, n]^3, {n, 1, nmax}], {Subscript[u, 0] -> 0, 
 Subscript[u, nmax + 1] -> 0}]

pars[nmax_] := Table[Subscript[u, j], {j, 1, nmax}]

(nsol3 = NSolve[rp[3], pars[3]]) // Timing

(*   {0.047, {{Subscript[u, 1] -> -1.10821 - 0.0022525 I, 
Subscript[u, 2] -> 1.26395\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0.0302327 I, 
Subscript[u, 3] -> 
0.673588\[VeryThinSpace]- 0.564175 I}, {Subscript[u, 
1] -> -1.10821 + 0.0022525 I, 
Subscript[u, 2] -> 1.26395\[VeryThinSpace]- 0.0302327 I, 
Subscript[u, 3] -> 0.673588\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0.564175 I},
......
{Subscript[u, 1] -> 0., Subscript[u, 2] -> 0., 
Subscript[u, 3] -> 0.}}}   *)

(nsol4 = NSolve[rp[4], pars[4]]) // Timing
```

You get 27 solutions for nsol3 in 0.047 seconds. For 4 parameters you get 81 solutions in 0.266 seconds, for nsol5 243 solutions in 1.734 seconds. Number of solutions raises with a factor 3^nmax and calculation time raises by a factor of about 7^nmax.

For 20 parameters you would get 27*3^17 = 3486784401 solutions in 0.047*7^17 seconds, that are about 347441 years.

Comment: Since it is recurrent  system the linear part (without u[n]^3) is easily solved by RSolve/RSolveValue. Unfortunately, RSolve cannot solve it with the nonlinear part. If one could think how to utilize the solution of linear part, then may be one have a chance?